# mysqli_fetch_array to php variable trash

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I upload 4 photos in a folder, and the names of the photos on mysql. Then i "SELECT" the names of the files, and put them in the array picArray as shown. But when i try to echo the contents, although i take the right names, it seem that they cant be used as a directory path.

Here is the code:

```
                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mypass","fixit");
                $con->set_charset("utf8");
                $repId=$repId+1;
                $qr = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM photos WHERE report='$repId'");


                $picArray = Array();

                while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($qr) ) {
                    $picArray[] = $row['name'];
                }   

        ?>      

            <div>
                <img  id="img1" src="uploads/<?php echo $repId ?>/<?php echo $picArray[0] ?>" />
                <img  id="img2" src="uploads/<?php echo $repId ?>/<?php echo $picArray[1] ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img  id="img3" src="uploads/<?php echo $repId ?>/<?php echo $picArray[2] ?>"  />
                <img  id="img4" src="uploads/<?php echo $repId ?>/<?php echo $picArray[3] ?>"  />
            </div>
```

What i should mention, is that when i:

```
echo $picArray[0];
echo $picArray[1];
echo $picArray[2];
echo $picArray[3];
```

i get:

```
rafiki.png rafiki2.png
rafiki3.pngrafiki4.png
```

which means that the array has newline and spaces on it... Why is this happening?

Comment: I hope you're escaping `$repId`

Comment: you mean escape to string? $repId makes no problem to me. Its working right. Should i escape to string picArray elements?

Comment: it's generally good practice to escape variables before they're entered into a query, unless the system already handles it. You don't need to escape to string the picArray elements.

Comment: `var_dump` your arrays for quicker and more exact debugging. And for $picArray items, use `trim`

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably new lines stored with the picture names in the database  this is a fix but you should clean up you data

```
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($qr) ) {
                    $picArray[] = trim($row['name']);
                }
```